# How to change /etc/resolv.conf file in an OpenShift pod

Tags: docker, dns, openshift, openshift-origin

I have a docker image I deployed onto OpenShift (using oc new-app).  However, it's not working properly because of a missing dns search entry in /etc/resolv.conf.  When I create a container from my docker image and run it, I can specify the parmater --dns-search.

How can I do something similar during the deployment of my image onto OpenShift with oc new-app?

Comment: What OpenShift instance is this? Did you build your own OpenShift cluster? Are you using Minishift, ``oc cluster up``, or some third party hosting for OpenShift?

Comment: Is the search domain an external one, not hosted on your Openshift? Normally, you can reference the "neighbours" by using just their name (eg. http://db could be just fine)

Comment: Also, take a look at https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/17316

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, this is OpenShift enterprise.  Not using any third-party hosting, this is hosted by my own company.

Comment: @ptrk, thanks for the link, but couldn't find anything there that can help me.  The search domain is internal, but it's not fully qualified, e.g. "subdomain" instead of "subdomain.example.com".

Comment: One way is to create a Service with required name in the project and assign it an external IP for the external host. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_service.html#manually-assign-ip-service

Comment: Having search domains for external domains is probably not a good idea as could conflict with way searches are done for internal cluster services.

Comment: Also see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html#saas-define-service-using-fqdn This one is probably better as can use original FQDN and not an IP.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the config Map of Node in master server

```
# oc get cm -n openshift-node
```

for all compute nodes edit the config map by below command.( Only need to perform in master server)

```
#  oc edit cm node-config-compute  -n openshift-node

......
dnsBindAddress: 127.0.0.1:53
    dnsDomain: cluster.local
    dnsIP: 10.0.80.11
    dnsNameservers: null
    dnsRecursiveResolvConf: /etc/origin/node/resolv.conf
.......
```

Edit dnsIP section with your DNS IP. Then restart the service

```
# systemctl restart atomic-openshift-node.service
```

The DNS ip will be prepended in all /etc/resolv.conf file of Pods.

Detail Information is present [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/master_node_configuration.html#node-configuration-files)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1. Enter the container if it is running using: docker exec -it
   container_id bash  and then edit the file, then use docker commit to
   save the changes.
2. You can add the name in the Dockerfile: CMD cat name >>/etc/resolve.conf
3. Mount the resolv.conf from your system to the image.

Comment: None of these will really work in the context of OpenShift/Kubernetes.

Comment: I dont see a reason why not. If he uses docker image and change it it will apply to the pod. And the problem he describes can be solved by this.

Comment: My understanding is that Kubernetes replaces the ``/etc/resolv.conf`` file so any changes in it from the image wouldn't be used. So you have to use the Kubernetes configuration mechanism to affect changes to the file.

Comment: You can find some information about it in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/ but I don't know whether they same applies with OpenShift due to different internal DNS used. That is, how things are different based on use of SkyDNS, kube-dns or CoreDNS.